# Cannot find name 'before'.ts(2304)

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am using jest with typescript and I am getting an error on "before" calls:

```
Cannot find name 'before'.ts(2304)
```

I have @types/jest already installed.

---

Update: looks like jest doesn't have before - might have been tests from a different testing framework, so in this case, Typescript was correctly identifying a non-existant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these [global methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/api#methods), there is no `before` method. I think you are looking for [beforeAll](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/api#beforeallfn-timeout).

Comment: Nice, I guess typescript was just doing it's job there when I thought it was wrong.